# SwiftUI list duplicates children depending on open groups in macOS BigSur

Tags: listview, swiftui, macos-big-sur

I faced a problem that swiftui list doesn't show items correctly.

Check two screenshots:
Item "Two" has 2 children: "SubitemOne" and "SubitemTwo", when "SubitemOne" is closed the second child duplicates the last element of the first level array.
[image: Screenshot 1]

If we open "SubitemOne" the element is rendered correctly.
[image: Screenshot 2]

I created sample project that shows the problem - https://github.com/kmalyshev/ListProblemExample.

The code is the following:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    let data = Item.getSampleData()
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            
            VStack {
                List(data, id: \.id, children: \.children) { item in
                    Text(item.name)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}

struct Item: Codable {
    
    let id: UUID
    let name: String
    let children: [Item]?
    
    init(id: UUID = UUID(), name: String, children: [Item]? = nil) {
        self.id = id
        self.name = name
        self.children = children
    }
    
    static func getSampleData() -> [Item] {
        
        [
            Item(name: "One"),
            Item(
                name: "Two",
                children: [
                    Item(
                        name: "SubitemOne",
                        children: [
                            Item(name: "LastOne"),
                            Item(name: "LastTwo"),
                        ]
                    ),
                    Item(name: "SubitemTwo"),
                ]
            ),
            Item(name: "Three"),
        ]
    }
    
}
```

My macOS version is 11.0.1. Do you know any workarounds?

Comment: I suspect it's a bug in SwiftUI since exactly the same code works well on iOS. MacOS 11.1 Beta didn't fix it.

Comment: My current workaround - I stopped using list with children, switched to manual creation of the nested structure. Something like here https://fivestars.blog/code/swiftui-hierarchy-list.html. It allows to control the state of the groups, which are set to "open" by default, temporary resolves the issue but it's not a production level solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem has been solved. I reported the bug to Apple.

https://feedbackassistant.apple.com/feedback/8955055

They fixed it as a result of some internal updates.